# Equivalent definition of a graded ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition, graded-rings

Is this an equivalent definition for a graded ring?

Let $R$ be a ring. We say that $R$ is graded if there are subgroups $R_n, n\in \mathbb{Z}$  of $R$ such that given $x\in R$, there are $x_n \in R_n$ such that $x=\sum x_n$ where the sum is finite, i.e., there are only a finite number of non-zero $x_n$ such that this expression is unique.

The definition I am familiar is:

$R$ is *graded* if $R=\bigoplus R_n$ as abelian groups and $R_nR_m\subset R_{m+n}$

Comment: You have now changed your question, incorporating my answer and the numerous comments in the new version. You shouldn't do that because now the answer seems not to address the question. Moreover everything has been answered so you should try to understand on your own  what you have been told and review the definition of direct sum.

Comment: Apologies, that was not what I meant, I'll left the question in original form.

Comment: I just want to understand why some books use the first definition, I think that the function $\(x_n\)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \rightarrow \sum x_n$ is bijective

Comment: Thanks, Jr: I have deleted the edit mentioning your  former change in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your definition is not equivalent to the usual one since it says nothing about the compatibility of the grading with the multiplicative structure of the ring.

For example let $k$ be a field and   write $R=k[X]=\oplus R_n$ with $R_n=kX^{2n}\oplus kX^{2n+1}$.
Then $R$ is graded in your sense but not in the usual sense because $X^3\in R_1$ and yet  $X^3\cdot X^3 \notin R_2$

Comment: and what about I if add the hipothesis: $R_nR_m\subset R_{n+m}$, in my definition,is it equivalent now?

Comment: @Jr.         Yes $ \\\\\ $

Comment: why?How do I show that?

Comment: Your definition *was* equivalent to just $R=\bigoplus R_n$

Comment: the elements of $\bigoplus R_n$ are of the form $\(x_n\)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$, aren't they?

Comment: @Jr.: No. Those are the elements of $\prod R_n$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Could you indicate a reference that works with the first definition I gave,or at least prove that they are the same?thanks

Comment: @ZhenLin I fortgot to point out that only a finite number of $x_n$ is non-zero